# How to group the data of a dataframe by age ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graphics, pandas-groupby

I want to group the data of a dataframe by age ranges to be able to graph the age group that presented the most road incidents, but I cannot obtain the group by age ranges.

The dataframe is as follows:

```
mty['V1_Edad'] = 'SD', '57', '34', '27', '39', '35', '28', '32', '45', '44', '79',
       '50', '33', '40', '23', '22', '37', '20', '53', '18', 0, '21',
       '26', '36', '24', '48', '49', '66', '43', '54', '67', '19', '38',
       '31', '69', '80', '41', '25', '56', '42', '51', '59', '52', '30',
       '73', '68', '60', '46', '61', '71', '29', '47', '58', '70', '55',
       '72', '65', '17', '77', '62', '63', '75', '16', '78', '64', '74',
       '76', '85', '86', '15', '88', '82', '84', '13', '14', '81', '83',
       '0', 'NP', 'NO', 'HUYO', 'SI', '11', 'ESTACIONADO ', '42|', 'MP',
       'Otro', 'S/', 'N/R', 'N/L', 'HUYE DEL  LUGAR', 'NO VISIBLE', '87',
       '94', '90', '12', 'S/D', '1900-01-29 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-20 00:00:00', '1900-01-26 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-01 00:00:00', '1900-02-16 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-31 00:00:00', '1900-02-23 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-18 00:00:00', '1900-01-22 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-23 00:00:00', '1900-02-06 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-21 00:00:00', '1900-02-15 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-28 00:00:00', '1900-02-22 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-07 00:00:00', '1900-02-04 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-10 00:00:00', '1900-02-14 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-25 00:00:00', '1900-02-19 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-27 00:00:00', '1900-02-17 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-09 00:00:00', '1900-02-08 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-13 00:00:00', '1900-01-28 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-03 00:00:00', '1900-01-30 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-11 00:00:00', '1900-01-24 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-05 00:00:00', '1900-01-18 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-12 00:00:00', '1900-03-03 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-02 00:00:00', '1900-02-24 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-19 00:00:00', '1900-02-25 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-27 00:00:00', '1900-03-02 00:00:00',
       '1900-02-26 00:00:00', '1900-02-20 00:00:00',
       '1900-01-17 00:00:00', '1900-03-05 00:00:00', 'SIN CONDUCTOR',
       ' HUYO', '6', '242', 'sd', '89', '96', '354', '7', '9',
       'no proporciona', 'se retiró', 'Np', ' SD'], dtype=object
```

After removing all rows that do not contain numeric data, the code I took to try to divide by ranges is as follows:

```
print(mty['V1_Edad'].head(50).to_dict())
{1: '57', 2: '34', 3: '27', 4: '39', 5: '35', 6: '39', 7: '28', 8: '32',
9: '34', 10: '27', 12: '45', 13: '35', 14: '44', 16: '79', 17: '44', 
19: '50', 20: '45', 22: '33', 24: '40', 25: '40', 27: '23', 28: '22', 
30: '37', 32: '20', 34: '53', 35: '18', 37: '21', 38: '26', 39: '53', 
40: '36', 41: '24', 42: '48', 43: '50', 45: '36', 47: '49', 51: '66', 
52: '35', 53: '27', 54: '33', 55: '21', 56: '33', 57: '37', 58: '27', 
59: '36', 60: '43', 61: '54', 62: '37', 63: '53', 64: '67', 65: '19'}
total_count = mty.groupby('V1_Edad')['V1_Edad'].value_counts()
bins=[-1,15,40,60,80]
labels = ['0-15', '16-40', '41-60', '61-80']
```

But all I get is a table with 4s or 1s, and not a table with the actual grouping and count of the data.

The data I put is unique values, because the dataframe has more than 2000 data.

What could you do to improve the code?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible (dataframe creation)

Comment: It is already fixed, I just want to know how I can divide the dataframe by age group, according to the data of the column that I put.

Comment: Your column has wide variety of data types. You may have to filter out the numeric ages first. Ie: dates aren't ages, so you'd want to remove those first???

Comment: Yes, I have already removed everything other than ages, still the code to try to set the bins does not work for me

Comment: Please add the output of `mty.to_dict()` to your question, @Asairi. Then we can help.

Comment: Or `mty.head().to_dict()`. Your code is still not reproducible...

Comment: The mty.to_dict( ) is ready

Comment: You have 3 different data types in there I'd start by breaking those up so you can run a function for each.

Comment: @Asairi you misunderstood me. Please add this code to your file: `print('MTY:', mty.to_dict())`. Then run the file, then copy the text that starts with `MTY:` and everything after it, and paste it into your question.

Comment: the modification is done with the data in dictionary mode

Answer (score 0):

Your description is still a little unclear, but here's an example using your data to get a histogram dataframe using `numpy`. I set your dictionary = d.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['mycolumn'])
df['mycolumn'] = df['mycolumn'].astype('int')
bins=[-1,15,40,60,80]
labels = ['0-15', '16-40', '41-60', '61-80']
binned_values = np.histogram(df['mycolumn'], bins=bins)[0].tolist() # use [0] to just get the counts
df_hist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(labels, binned_values)), orient='index').reset_index()
df_hist.columns = ['ranges', 'counts']

df_hist

  ranges  counts
0   0-15       0
1  16-40      31
2  41-60      16
3  61-80       3
```

using pandas to create a plot

```
histplot = pd.DataFrame.hist(df, column='mycolumn', bins=bins)

array([[<AxesSubplot:title={'center':'mycolumn'}>]], dtype=object)
```